# Assign values to numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

Let say we create this np.array:

```
A = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
```

So, A is:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I would like to assign some values to A like that:

```
A[[0,2]][:,[1,3]] = 9999
```

In order to obtain:

```
array([[ 0,  9999,  2,  9999],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9999, 10, 9999]])
```

But this doesn't work. What is the proper way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to get those open meshes, which when used for indexing into the array would be [*`broadcasted`*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and thus could be used for assigning values into it, like so -

```
A[np.ix_([0,2],[1,3])] = 9999
```